# Assembler, printing a text

Tags: assembly

In data segment i have.

```
  >.data      
>Title     db     "My title", 0  
>Text    db "Hello!!!", oah, odh, 0  
>.data ?
```

Can you tell me guys what oah, odh, 0 means here?

Comment: Can you add some points to your question to making it look complete ?

Comment: Should be `0ah` (10 decimal) which is LINEFEED and `0dh` (13 decimal) which is CARRIAGE RETURN. When that string is output to the display the cursor is moved to the beginning of the next line. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline